# How to debug DLL injection in IDA?

Tags: ida, debugging, dll, injection

Recently, I've been cracking a crackme DLL, and I need to inject it into a process, to see if it worked.

However, I've ran into a problem. I cannot seem to find how to debug DLL injection inside of ida. I've tried Debugger->Attach to Process, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility: Insert a "code cave" into your hosting process, and let it load the DLL. For how to do it in a "generic" way in x64, look [here](https://www.tophertimzen.com/blog/windowsx64Shellcode/). An important step of this is how to get the address of the `kernel32.dll`:

```
get_OS_DllAddresses:
mov rax, gs:[60h]               ; PEB
mov rax, [rax + 18h]            ; PEB::Ldr
mov rax, [rax + 20h]            ; PEB::Ldr.InMemoryOrderModuleList
mov rax, [rax]                  ; 1st entry
mov r15, [rax + 20h]            ; ntdll.dll base address!
mov rax, [rax]                  ; 3nd entry
mov rax, [rax + 20h]            ; kernel32.dll base address!
ret
```

[PEB](http://terminus.rewolf.pl/terminus/structures/ntdll/_PEB_combined.html) → [PEB::Ldr](http://terminus.rewolf.pl/terminus/structures/ntdll/_PEB_LDR_DATA_combined.html) → walk the `InMemoryOrderModuleList` linked list ([LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY](http://terminus.rewolf.pl/terminus/structures/ntdll/_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY_combined.html)).

After running this snippet, you have in **`rax`** the address of `kernel32.dll` (correctly also in the case of ASLR), and in **`r15`** the address of `ntdll.dll`.

If you study the example given in the above link, you learn how to extract the necessary **`LoadLibrary`** calls (for your DLL to be checked), and the **`GetProcAddress`** calls, in case your DLL exports API calls.

A simple way to get the "shellcode" bytes is to make a little Assembler project e.g. in VisualStudio and let it create the binary code for you.

Comment: This seems a little odd. We start out with the `InMemoryOrderModuleList`, then seem to proceed with the `InInitializationOrderLinks`? Not that I'm saying that this can't be done, but isn't this relying a bit too much on empirical data? `InLoadOrderModuleList` always has `your.exe` -> `ntdll.dll` -> `kernel32.dll` -> `kernelbase.dll`, but the memory order technically depends on the base address.

Answer (score -2):

dynamic debugging for dll you should use x64dbg or ollydbg. both can load dll to execute and debug.